# How strong is the evidence for the effectiveness of psychoanalysis in the treatment of depression?

Tags: depression, psychoanalysis

I often hear claims that psychoanalysis is ineffective, takes too long, is just pseudo-science, that other therapies such as cognitive-behavioural should be preferred or even that it should be entirely dismissed. In [this talk](https://youtu.be/GOwJKbJxVUM) however, the speaker seems to claim that psychoanalysis has quite a bit of empirical evidence going for it, which surprised and confused me.

How strong is the research on psychoanalysis as a treatment for depression?

I am not sure if this is too opinion based, so please help me make it better if it is (e.g. 'what is some of the best evidence on psychoanalysis as a treatment for depression?')

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE.  There is a big discussion in meta concerning pseudoscience of psychoanalysis and that is at https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2242. There are also [limitations to CBT](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/1977) along with many who regard CBT to not be as effective as portrayed. For CBT and depression there is https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/13516

Comment: @ChrisRogers thank you, I will look into those.